# How to submit all information from a JSP page including two other pages?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a main JSP file that includes other JSP files, I want to submit a request from the main page to include the parameters in all files.

The scenario is that my main page includes two other pages:

- a page with search criteria fields and search button
- a page with the results table and a save button

When I submit the changes in the results table, my servlet doesn't see the information from the other included JSP page (search criteria). How can I fix this?

My question could also be in another way: is it possible to make to sub JSP pages submit the same form from the parent JSP page?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Do your search and results page have separate forms? Submitting a form only gathers data from inside its `<form></form>` tags, not from other forms on the same page.

Comment: So is it possible to make the two pages inside one form?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by t0mppa wrap the two inserts in your main page with the  tags.  Any fields inside them will be submitted.